# iOS Apple Map native links - URL Scheme examples

Tags: ios, objective-c, maps

In one of my projects I'm capturing the Lat/Long coords in a core data store, and later on providing this information in an email with Attached PDF.. On the receiving end, I'd like the convenience of another iPhone user to be able to click on the link, and go to that location in Apple Maps

I find the native apple map comes up, but it's simply an open map view w/no pin:

```
NSString *appleLink2 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://maps.apple.com/maps   
ll=%@,%@",self.lat,self.lon];
```

I'm creating the clickable in a common fashion with a `CGRect`, and `NSURL`

It appears on the surface that I should probably get the street address instead of the Lat/Long coords also, and use the address for better map resolution... Thoughts?

Also, I'm looking for examples of Apples URL Schemes to query strings mentioned in the Docs, but can't find any real examples...  `ll =` , `son =`, `t =` , `z =`.  I understand `saddr` and `daddr`, and am surprised that I can't find any reference or real examples anywhere.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want the pin to be placed on the map in Apple's Maps app, use a 'q' instead of 'll' in the URL:

```
NSString *appleLink2 = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"http://maps.apple.com/maps?q=%@,%@", self.lat, self.lon];
```

Comment: Thanks Jason, this was exactly what I was looking for!  I can now provide this link and any alternative (google) links to give the recipient a choice.

Answer (score 1):

The following apple link has all details for the questions

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/Articles/MapLinks.html

Comment: This doc doesn't detail the other options, and what values can be placed in the t=?, or z=?..  I was looking for meaningful definition :)

Answer (score 1):

USE `NSString` for `URL`

```
NSString *appleLink2 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://maps.apple.com/maps   
ll=%@,%@",self.lat,self.lon];

NSURL *myUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:[appleLink2 stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```

Then use myUrl is as URL.

Comment: I should have stated that the URL I was using was this:    NSURL* url = [NSURL URLWithString:appleLink2]; ..